Best practice for including remote data sources in an R package?
When authoring an R package, it is often good practice to bake in some datasets, usually for educational/tutorial purposes. There's a chapter about this in Hadley Wickham's book about R packages: https://r-pkgs.org/data.html
I have a use-case where there are several datasets that I'd like to also make available through the package, but they are actually remote. I use {dbplyr} frequently and write a lot of R code to interact with my databases, but by their nature they must be remote.
So, I'm often doing something like


production <- DBI::dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host     = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_SERVER"),
  dbname   = Sys.getenv("PRODUCTION_DATABASE"),
  user     = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
  password = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
)

my_table <- dplyr::tbl(production, dbplyr::in_schema("our_database", "my_table"))

head(my_table)

Is it possible to include in my custom R package something like this:
head(my_pkg::my_table)

From what I can tell, this case is not really covered in Hadley's book. Maybe section 7.2 - Internal data?

I think this depends a lot on your use case. Do you want to distribute the password with your package? (Probably not.) What about the username? The DB name? If your package is to be installed and used by folks who have the credentials stored in environment variables as you, then, maybe have a function that creates the production connection. (And documentation that lists the expected environment variables that need to be set up.)

If you want to include a sample of the data in the package (or even the full data in the package) that can be accessible without a db connection, then that's no different than including any other data set--it doesn't matter that you got it from the database and not some other data source, you will put it in the package (by writing in the data/ folder as an .rda file, probably) and your users will get it from the package.

Also note that the "Internal Data" book section that you link to is for data that is not available to users of your package, but is only available internally within the package. It's like an unexported function that your package functions use internally, but you don't expect your users to use. It sounds like you do want your users to be able to access this data, so internal data is the wrong choice. You want to look at the previous section, Exported Data.

How best to approach this depends on the sensitivity of the data, the intended audience, and the purpose for which you want to make things available. Below are four different approaches you might try.
In each case, I have written these as a demo_function that your users might call when familiarising themselves with your package. I assume you might include these in a vignette or your documentation.
Note that for including data in a GitHub repository, there is a limit on the file size.

1) simulated database connections
dbplyr includes options for simulating database connections.

Sensitivity - you can create your own example data extract of safe data
Audience - public
Purpose - test or demonstrate database translation.

demo_function = function(){

  data(starwars)
  # simulated connection
  remote_df = tbl_lazy(starwars, con = simulate_postgres())
  # computation
  out = mutate(remote_df, substring_col = grepl("Luke", name)))
  return(out)
}


2) SQLite database
SQLite is available within R. You can include an SQLite database file within the extdata folder of your package.

Sensitivity - you can create your own example data extract of safe data
Audience - public
Purpose - demonstrate connecting to a database for basic analysis

Setup during package development:
path = system.file("extdata", "testing", package = "my.new.package")
db_path = file.path(path, "testing_sqlite.db")
db_conn = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db_path)

# add table
data(iris)
DBI::dbWriteTable(db_conn, "iris_table", iris)

Use:
demo_function = function(){
  path = system.file("extdata", "testing", package = "my.new.package")
  db_path = file.path(path, "testing_sqlite.db")
  db_conn = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db_path)

  my_table = dplyr::tbl(db_conn, "iris")
  return(my_table)
}


3) demonstration code
You could write a demonstration R file that is given to users to customise for their own analysis.

Sensitivity - no data in package, no credentials in demonstration
Audience - internal focus, but safe for public
Purpose - setup users to begin following your example

Script saved to extdata:
# INSTRUCTIONS:
# Edit the lines of this file to provide the required connection details.

production <- DBI::dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host     = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_SERVER"),
  dbname   = Sys.getenv("PRODUCTION_DATABASE"),
  user     = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
  password = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
)

my_table <- dplyr::tbl(production, dbplyr::in_schema("our_database", "my_table"))

head(my_table)

Helper function:
demo_function = function(){
  folder = getwd()
  
  # locations
  to_dir = file.path(normalizePath(folder), "demo_script")
  from_dir = system.file("extdata", "demo_script", package = "my.new.package")
  
  # copy
  file.copy(
    list.files(from_dir, full.names = TRUE), 
    to_dir, 
    recursive = TRUE
  )
}


4) Separate credential file
You can save the credentials in a separate file that is not part of the package. This file can be provided to internal users alongside the package. When the package runs it will use the credential file if it is found otherwise error/warn/prompt (your choice).

Sensitivity - no data in package, no credentials in demonstration
Audience - internal focus, but safe for public
Purpose - quick start for users with internal data

demo_function = function(host = NULL, dbname = NULL, user = NULL, password = NULL, db = NULL){
  # load credential file if exists  
  credentials = "C:/expected/folder/credential_file.txt"
  if(file.exists(credentials)){
    con = file(credentials, "r")
    host = readLines(con, n = 1)
    dbname = readLines(con, n = 1)
    user = readLines(con, n = 1)
    password = readLines(con, n = 1)
    close(con)
  }
  
  # prompt if NULL
  if(is.null(host)){
    host = readline("What is the value of host?")  
  }
  if(is.null(dbname)){
    dbname = readline("What is the value of dbname?")  
  }
  if(is.null(user)){
    user = readline("What is the value of user?")  
  }
  if(is.null(password)){
    password  = readline("What is the value of password?")  
  }

  # return connection
  production <- DBI::dbConnect(
    RPostgres::Postgres(),
      host     = host,
      dbname   = dbname,
      user     = user,
      password = password
  )
}


Others have talked about different approaches of doing this. The below might be close to what you are after.
You could use .onload function to establish and verify connection.
If necessary, load the data there too.

Write a README file on how to add system environment variables. Here is an example.

Write an .onload function like this. In your case, it would be something like below.


.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  
  POSTGRES_SERVER <- Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_SERVER")
  PRODUCTION_DATABASE <- Sys.getenv("PRODUCTION_DATABASE")
  POSTGRES_USER <- Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_USER")
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD <- Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
  
  if(!nchar(POSTGRES_SERVER)) warning("POSTGRES_SERVER not found! Please follow instructions in README file.")
  
  tryCatch(expr = {
    connection <- DBI::dbConnect(
      RPostgres::Postgres(),
      host     = POSTGRES_SERVER,
      dbname   = PRODUCTION_DATABASE,
      user     = POSTGRES_USER,
      password = POSTGRES_PASSWORD)

    }, error = function(e){
      warning("Please ensure `.Rprofile` / `.Renviron` files are available at: ", Sys.getenv("R_USER"))
      warning("Could not connect to postgres server. Please follow instructions in README file.")
  }
)

If you want the data also, you could add this bit in the function.
   sample_data <- dplyr::tbl(production, dbplyr::in_schema("our_database", "my_table"))
   usethis::use_data(sample_data)

This function will run when your package user execute library(your_package_name). If their setup according to your readme is not done right, they will get the warnings that you establish in the function.
If all goes well, they will be able to load the data using:
dta <- your_package_name::sample_data
or
data(sample_data)
If your data is sensitive, consider adding your rda files in the data directory in your build ignore or .gitignore. That way, the user only gets the data if they have the database credentials set up correctly.
